# How can I open another activity using spinner item selection in xamarin.forms only?

Tags: xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.forms, spinner, menuitem

I've tried this and it looks like majority of search results reference to Android studio. I'm using visual studio, xamarin forms.

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner> (Resource.Id.spinner);

    spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs> (spinner_ItemSelected);
    var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource (
            this, Resource.Array.my_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

    adapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
    spinner.Adapter = adapter;
}
```

The spinner loads perfectly but the item selected method opens the activity on loading.

```
private void spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
 SetContentView (Resource.Layout.page1);
}
```

How best can I load the activity on specific item selection. **Note: the items are referenced in the Strings.xml**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Spinner chooses the first item by default when initialized, it will fire `spinner_ItemSelected`

You can add a conditional judgment to your `spinner_ItemSelected` method:

```
private void spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
 {
    var index = e.Parent.SelectedItemPosition; //base on the select position
    var obj = e.Parent.SelectedItem; // base on the selectitem value(string) 
    // xxx is your conditions
    if(index == xxx)
     {
      SetContentView (Resource.Layout.page1);
     }
    // or 
    if(obj.ToString().Equals("xxx"))
     {
      SetContentView (Resource.Layout.page1);
     }
 }
```